# Student's t-distribution CDF R base documentation

Tags: r, function, statistics, probability

In the context of the Student's t-distribution cumulative distribution function, R Version 4.3.1's `?dt` documentation highlights the following result:

[image]

However, upon attempting to verify the accuracy of this formula, an inconsistency arises, as illustrated in the following code snippet:

```r
v <- 5
t <- -1

## Student's t-distribution cumulative distribution function
pt(q = t, df = v, lower.tail = TRUE, ncp = 0)
#> [1] 0.1816087

## Application of the theorical result where there is a discrepancy 
## based on what is mentioned in R Version 4.3.1's ?dt documentation
1 - pbeta(q = v / (v + t^2), shape1 = v/2, shape2 = 1/2, 
          ncp = 0,lower.tail = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.6367825
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This issue raises questions about the accuracy of the documentation. I am seeking clarification to determine whether the problem lies in the documentation itself before reporting a potential mistake to the R project. This inquiry is related to a theoretical concept, where a detailed explanation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782056/students-t-distribution-cumulative-distribution-function)

Comment: I don't think the derivation is correct. You should refer to equation (7) in the webpage https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Studentst-Distribution.html

Comment: Maybe worth noting that this section was only added a year ago: https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/commit/61e301ad9720195f6756317458761df9bfbc0f2d

Comment: Thank you Ben Bolker for pointing this out. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm looks like an error. Here is a valid identity:

```r
v <- 5
t <- -1

## Student's t-distribution cumulative distribution function
pt(q = t, df = v, lower.tail = TRUE, ncp = 0)
#> [1] 0.1816087

x = (t + sqrt(t * t + v)) / (2.0 * sqrt(t * t + v))
pbeta(q = x, shape1 = v/2, shape2 = v/2, ncp = 0, lower.tail = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.1816087
```

And another one, closer to the claim of the R doc:

```r
pbeta(q = v / (v + t^2), shape1 = v/2, shape2 = 1/2, 
            ncp = 0,lower.tail = TRUE) / 2
#> [1] 0.1816087
```

Answer (score 3):

***First of all, I don't that the formula in R's manual is correct!***

You should use the following formula to calculate CDF

```
> 1 / 2 + 1 / 2 * (pbeta(1, v / 2, v) - pbeta(v / (v + t^2), v / 2, 1 / 2)) * sign(t)
[1] 0.1816087
```

The formula refers to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Studentst-Distribution.html, see equation (7)

[image]

---

## Break-down into the function

As we can see that, the CDF function depends on the sign of `t`. Note that `pbeta(1, a, b) = 1` always holds, so the expression can be simplified further and written in a piece-wise manner in terms of `t`, say:

- If `t>0`

```
1 - 0.5 * pbeta(v / (v + t^2), v / 2, 1 / 2)
```

- Otherwise

```
0.5 * pbeta(v / (v + t^2), v / 2, 1 / 2)
```

Note that you have `t <- -1`, which is negative, you should apply the second expression (be aware of the factor `0.5` before `pbeta`), and you will see that

```
> 0.5 * pbeta(v / (v + t^2), v / 2, 1 / 2)
[1] 0.1816087
```

Comment: Thank you ThomasIsCoding for pointing out another alternative.

Comment: @luifrancgom I added more explanation in my answer.

Comment: Thank you again  ThomasIsCoding. Now I understand more!!! I will try to deduce  the case when t > 0 using the probability distribution function. I was able initially to deduce only the case where t < 0.